# A book where animals are named after instruments

Tags: story-identification, animals

I was listening to one of the sci-fi radio links on either Live365 or George Norrie or BOA... It is written by a religious (Catholic or Christian) teacher (make). It is a sci-fi book where animals are named after instruments. I can swear I looked it up and the cover is orange and has a person or human type thing walking.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More clarification is needed. When did you hear about this book? Do you know when it might have been published? You say you already looked it up? When? Anything else other than the color of the cover?
Maybe one of these radio stations (what are they? I've never heard of them) can help you track it down.

Comment: Could it be 'The Alphabetical Forest' by Sondis Florin   http://www.amazon.com/The-Alphabetical-Forest-ebook/dp/B00501HT9Y/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1370654862&sr=1-1